# Is it possible to copy a class' __repr__ method to another in python?

Tags: python, representation

I was messing around with some (frankly useless) python code the other day that attempted to make a previously unsubclassable class like `bool` subclassable, this is as far as I got:

```
def make_subclassable(old_cls):
    """
    Make a class that was previously unavailable for subclassing now subclassable.

    Examples of unsubclassable classes are 'bool', 'EllipsisType', and 'NotImplementedType'.
    """

    class _faketype(ABCMeta):
        @classmethod
        def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
            return isinstance(instance, (new_cls, old_cls))

    new_cls = _faketype('Subclassable' + old_cls.__name__.title(), \
                   old_cls.__mro__[1:], # don't include the class itself
                   dict(old_cls.__dict__)
                   )

    return new_cls
```

The problem has to do with the new class' `__repr__` method. For example:

```
>>> SubclassableBool = make_subclassable(bool)
>>> repr(SubclassableBool()) # should display 'False'
'<SubclassableBool object at 0x028C9210>'
```

When I create the new class with `_faketype`, the entire class dict from the old class gets copied over into the new class, and everything else seems to work except for `__repr__`. Is there any way I might be able to get the old `__repr__` into the new class?

Note: The solution may be hackish, as I'm more so interested in whether this is possible or not than a clean solution, however it would be nice if they were in pure python.

Comment: There are a bunch of subtle problems here relating to how special methods work, but there are also not-so-subtle problems. For example, you haven't actually made a `bool` or anything that would hold the data a `bool` does. Where would `bool.__repr__` find the data it needs to look for?

Comment: I thought saying `SubclassableBool()` would instantiate a "bool" instance just like saying `bool()` would, wouldn't it? Since it inherits essentially everything from `bool`, it would also inherit it's `__init__` method and other magic methods, or at least that's what I thought it would do.

Comment: Also, what are said subtle problems?

Comment: `bool.__init__` doesn't actually initialize anything; in fact, `bool.__init__ is object.__init__`. Even `bool.__new__` doesn't create a `bool`; it returns either the object `True` or `False`. `bool.__repr__` doesn't look for dict entries or anything a normal Python object would have; it looks for the `ob_ival` entry in the C-level `PyBoolObject` struct, which your object won't have. I'm not sure what's going on that seems to cause the slot wrappers you've grabbed from `bool.__dict__` to be ignored instead of TypeErroring.

Comment: Is this purely about `bool`, or will this logic apply to all classes created in this manner?

Comment: There's also the fact that `bool.__dict__` doesn't contain all of `bool`'s methods. `bool.__add__` comes from `int.__dict__`, for example. Not all of these problems apply to classes other than `bool`, but many of them will, with the particular problems depending on what class you're working with.